# Add a completion Listener To .setText() Method

Tags: android

I am trying to  find a way to check whether a `setText` method that passes values from the database to the UI has finished and the value is visible on the screen.

How can I accomplish this? The sole purpose for this is for good user experience, I realize it takes afer seconds before the `TextView` is updated. So I want to add a progress bar and dismiss it when the `TextView` is updated.

Answer (score -1):

> Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) .. execute your database query in  `doInBackground()` and
>   update your UI in  `onPostExecute()`
>
> you can show progress bar in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss dialog in post
>   execute